# Alinhar um `<span>` no centro vertical de um `<li>` sem alterar o restante do texto

Tags: html5, css3

Tenho uma lista não ordenada que precisa se manter do mesmo formato, porque ela se trata de um menu lateral montado dinamicamente. Mais ou menos assim:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a> Link 1 <span> Algum texto </span> </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a> Link 2 </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a> Link 3 </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Esse `<span>` que se encontra dentro do `<li>` deve se manter alinhado verticalmente, mesmo quando o texto do link for muito grande e precisar ocupar duas linhas ou mais. Mais ou menos assim:

[image: Exemplo de como deve ficar]

Então, até o momento não obtive sucesso. Consigo verticalizar a `<span>` em determinadas situações, mas não em todas.

Alguém poderia me dar um auxílio?

Comment: Qual o conteúdo que esse span recebe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minha solução original estava errada, eu não li que o objetivo era centralizar o `span` verticalmente. Nesse caso a solução é fazer com que o `li` seja exibido como `table`, e que tanto o `span` quanto o `link` sejam exibidos como `table-cell`. Células podem ser centralizadas verticalmente com `vertical-align: middle`

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
li {
    padding: 0 15px 10px;
    display: table;    
}
li a {
    color: blue;
    width: 150px;
    display: table-cell;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.options {
    color: red;
    width: 50px;
    padding-left: 35px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

#### [Exemplo funcional](http://jsfiddle.net/aaccioly/D929K/)

Comment: Funcionou muito bem. Já até integrei ao meu código principal. Valeu mesmo! ;)